# how to add user (post request) using express router and vuex service and actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In my application, I am creating a mock API and use it by accessing it through Vuex. In express routes, I am handling errors related to posting requests (add user). Now, I am not able to understand that how to communicate that into Vuex service and actions.

**express routes.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();

// routing entrypoint

router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  const data = require('./data/users.json');
  res.send(data);
});

router.post('/users', errorBoundaries, (req, res) => {
  const data = require('./data/users.json');
  res.status(200).send(data);
});

const errorBoundaries = (req, res, next) => {
  const { name } = req.body.name;
  const data = require('./data/users.422.json');
  if (name.length === 0) {
    return res.status(422).send(data);
  }
  // if string value is longer than 0, continue with next function in route
  next();
};

module.exports = router;
```

**Vuex service**

```
// how to communicate - needs some example

/**
 * @param {*} data object
 */
export async function addUsers(data) {
  const response = await http.post('/users', data);
  return response;
}
```

**Vuex actions and mutations**

```
  async addUserAction({ commit}, payload) {
       try {
         const resp = await service.addUsers({
         id: payload.id,
         firstName: payload.firstName,
         lastName: payload.lastName
        });
        commit('ADD_USERS',resp);
       } catch(error) {
        const message = error.response ? error.response.status : null;
        console.log(message);
      }
    }
```

**users.json**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Brown"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Frank",
        "lastName": "Lister"
    }
  ]
}
```

We need to add more error handling and pass that into UI by using Vuex. I need to understand that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the error message in Vuex state:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    errorMessage: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    updateErrorMessage (state, newErrorMessage) {
      state.errorMessage = newErrorMessage
    }
  }
})
```

and then commit it in your 'addActionUser':

```
async addUserAction({ commit}, payload) {
    try {
        const resp = await service.addUsers({
            id: payload.id,
            firstName: payload.firstName,
            lastName: payload.lastName
        });
        commit('ADD_USERS',resp);
    } catch(error) {
        const message = error.response ? error.response.status : null;
        console.log(message);
        commit('updateErrorMessage', message);
    }
}
```

then add a computed property to any interested component:

```
computed: {
    errorMessage() {
        return this.$store.state.errorMessage;
   }
}
```

And display the error message when it exists.

```
<div class="error" v-if="errorMessage">
   <span>{{ errorMessage }}</span>
</div>
```